# Apt-Mirror Error

Tags: repository, apt-mirror

Trying to create a local copy of the repository for Ubuntu 22.10.

Here is the file *mirror.list*:

```
set base_path    /mnt/ExternalSSD/apt-mirror
#
set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
set skel_path    $base_path/skel
set var_path     $base_path/var
set cleanscript $base_path/var/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
set postmirror_script $base_path/var/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     10
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

eb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-arm64 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-arm64 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-arm64 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-arm64 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-arm64 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonmagon/kdiskmark/ubuntu kinetic main
deb-arm64 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonmagon/kdiskmark/ubuntu kinetic main

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
clean http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
clean http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonmagon/kdiskmark/ubuntu
```

When you run the command *sudo apt-mirror*,  I have the following response:

```
root@Ubuntu-VM:/mnt/ExternalSSD/apt-mirror# apt-mirror
Downloading 404 index files using 8 threads...
Begin time: Wed Nov 30 09:33:11 2022
[8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Wed Nov 30 09:35:45 2022

Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-proposed/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-proposed/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-proposed/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-proposed/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-backports/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-backports/RI would be grateful for help in solving this problem.elease at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-backports/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/kinetic-backports/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Processing translation indexes: [TTTTTTTTTTTT]

Begin time: Wed Nov 30 09:42:45 2022
[10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Wed Nov 30 09:42:46 2022

Processing indexes: [PPPPPapt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic/mainI would be grateful for help in solving this problem./binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic/universe/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-security/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-security/universe/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-security/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-updates/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-updates/universe/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-updates/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-proposed/main/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-proposed/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-proposed/universe/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-proposed/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-backports/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-backports/universe/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/kinetic-backports/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
PPPPPPP]
```

I would be grateful for help in solving this problem.

Comment: Something that jumps out at me is that the base ports URL is http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ and you are missing "-ports/" in your config.

Comment: You right, this is my mistake. I corrected my mistake in /etc/apt/mirror.list, but I still have the same error "Failed to open Release file...".

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the error is that the files are not downloaded, so apt-mirror does not find them and raise an error.
Running wget on those URLs will reveal that it does not succeed because the source isn't secured/not signed by a CA.

To overpass that simply add this line to the mirror.list file:

```
set no_check_certificate 1
```